# ASP.NET send mail to multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hello i have a problem with sendig mails from asp.net web site. Here is my code

```
        private void mailgonder(string mail, string adsoyad)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress("my mail address", "my name");

        mm.Subject = "YENİ DUYURU";
        mm.Body = "Sistemde okumadığınız yeni bir duyuru bulunmaktadır.";

        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(mail, adsoyad));
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("my smtp client");
        sc.Port = 587;
        sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my username", "my password");
        sc.Send(mm);
    }
```

I want to send mail to 1500 users with same time. How can i do this in asp.net (we will have over 1000 member in this web project)

I can send like this to one person. But i don't know how can i send this to multiple persons

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MailMessage.To` is a collection, you can add as much as you want :

```
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user@user.com", "user1"));
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1@user.com", "user2"));
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user2@user.com", "user3"));
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user3@user.com", "user4"));
```

.....

until

```
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1499@user.com", "user1499"));
 mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1500@user.com", "user1500"));
```

**NOTE :** 
Restrictions may exist according to your mail server or access provider. For more efficiency, use a [mailing list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list).

Comment: You can't add 1000 people to To. Exchange server cannot handle it, and you will be banned from mail providers immediately.

Comment: Is this efficiency to send to 1500 persons ?

Comment: @OğuzSezer There are providers like sendgrid that do allow this.

Comment: That's why mailing lists exists

Comment: @OğuzSezer :  Everybody is not using  Exchange server.

Comment: No they won't. You need Sender Score Certificate to allow them accept your mails.

Comment: @EnderAriç : Of course not, you can use mailing list for that, or just send it 30 byt 30.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe the simplest approach by far is to make a contact group. Doing this will keep the amount of code written to a minimum. Here is a link explaining how to do so in Outlook [How to make a contact group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-and-edit-a-contact-group-formerly-distribution-lists-HA010354963.aspx)

Once you have the contact group setup, simply do this:

```
  String Devemail = "devgroup@whatever.com";
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
  message.To.Add(Devemail);
  //The rest of your code here
```

The rest of your code will work fine.
If someone has a better/simpler approach, please feel free to correct me.

EDIT: I am kind of shocked that we recommend he hard code 1500 email addresses into his code. Can someone give me a good reason for using that approach over using an email group?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send each user seperate emails. Do not, never, add more than 1 address to TO unless you have sender score certification, doing opposite will cause you get banned from mail providers since they would think you are a spammer. And also spam list is global, which means if you get banned from gmail, you will also get banned from hotmail or yahoo in a short period of time.

Just select for example 20 email addresses from database each time and loop that 20 and call your mailgonder method for each.

Other than what I wrote above, if you write multiple TO's, each of your users will see each others email adressses which is not cool from user perspective.